# If I draw something with a brush then use Live Paint, how do I get rid of the brush stokes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Say I have the following picture that I drew with a black brush then used Live Paint to color it.

How do I get rid of the black stroke?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First, with the Live Paint group selected, click `Expand` on the control bar to expand the Live Paint group.

Then use the Direct Selection Tool (the white arrow) to select the black. Then hit Delete.

[image: livepaint]

Comment: That deletes everything, including the green

Comment: If you've expanded the Live Paint group, and are using the Direct Selection tool to click the black, it should absolutely not delete the green.

Comment: @Scott That graphic is amazing! What program are you using to make that? I am constantly blown away by how helpful people are on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @supertrue It's merely a screen grab movie (there are a lot of apps to make movies of your screen) then used Photoshop CS6 extended to open the movie and Save For Web as GIF.